# How to use StackNavigator with DrawerNavigator and SwitchNavigator on React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

**TL;DR**: I need this result (with DrawerNavigator and StackNavigator navigation listed below):

[image]

### Structure:

---

I have this structure of screens:

In the root pages (represented by " • "), I need the navigation to be done with the **DrawerNavigator**, and the subpages (represented by " |_ ") I need to be navigated with the **StackNavigator**.

This is the behavior I would like to get:

```
• Account
|_ Create Account
|_ Login
|_ Forget Password

• Products
|_ Product detail
 |_ Ingredients

• Configuration
• About

• Cart
|_ Checkout
 |_ Finish Checkout
```

Drawer: **MainDrawer** with => createDrawerNavigator()

```
• Account
• Products
• Configuration
• About
• Cart
```

**SwitchNavigator**:

```
Start: StartCheck, // Screen component
App: MainDrawer, // Drawer
Welcome: WelcomeScreen, // Screen component
```

Component: **StartCheck** and **WelcomeScreen** is a `<Component />`

> StartCheck: this just check if have data on AsyncStorage, something like
>   "isFirstRun", and open **WelcomeScreen** or **MainDrawer** according of
>   result [[like this documentation]](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html).

### My code:

---

Screens:

```
const Screens = {
    account: {
        screen: AccountScreen,
        path: 'account'
    },
    products: {
        screen: ProductsScrren,
        path: 'products'
    },
    configuration: {
        screen: ConfigurationScrren,
        path: 'configuration'
    },
    about: {
        screen: AboutScrren,
        path: 'about'
    },
    cart: {
        screen: CartScrren,
        path: 'cart'
    },
};
```

MainDrawer:

```
const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
    ...Screens
}, {
    contentComponent: Sidebar,
    initialRouteName: 'products',
});
```

App Container with SwitchNavigator:

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        StartCheck: StartCheck, // Component

        App: MainDrawer, // Drawer
        Welcome: WelcomeScreen, // Component
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'StartCheck',
    }
));

export default AppContainer;
```

With this code, the **Header** does not appear, so I put the DrawerNavigator inside StackNavigator:

MainStack:

```
const MainStack = createStackNavigator({
    MainDrawer
});
```

And I modify App Container with SwitchNavigator:

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        StartCheck: StartCheck, // Component

        App: MainStack, // Stack
        Welcome: WelcomeScreen, // Component
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'StartCheck',
    }
));

export default AppContainer;
```

But in this way, the header **overlaps** the sidebar, and if I use the `headerMode: 'none'`, my header disappears from the other screens as well (not just the container).

[image]

I need this result (with DrawerNavigator and StackNavigator navigation list above):

[image]

And I also do not know where I can put the secondary screens (to open with the navigation method of StackNavigator).

Sorry for the big post, is that I tried to detail as much as possible, since I have been looking for a solution for some time but I have not found...

Comment: Have you tried nesting StackNavigators inside the DrawerNavigator?

Comment: How? You can post example?

Answer (score 1):

I will describe my idea in a textual form first:

After your Start screen is done with it's job, your're going to be in the drawer navigator, which is your **root node**

- Your drawer would either render StackNavigator or Pure Component|Screen.
  So, Drawer should have these routes:
- AccountStack | AuthStack.
- ProductsStack.
- Configuration Screen.
- About Screen.
- CheckoutStack.

**To show the header all the way**

- All StackNavigator is shipped with header /// done for screens rendered within stack.
- For your pure components like About screen, you could create a custom header and add it manually within these components.

**OR "not recommended from my point of view"**

- Render each pure screen like About screen within a stacknavigator just to save yourself the time for creating a custom header.

  ```
  const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
    Account: AccountStack,
    Product: ProductsStack,
    Configuration: ConfigScreen, // Pure Component
    About: AboutScreen, // Pure Component
    Cart: CartStack
  });

  // Ex stack:
  const AccountStack = createStackNavigator({
    CreateAcount: SignUpScreen,
    Login: LoginScreen,
    ForgotPassword: ForgotPasswordScreen
  });
  ```

Comment: Dude, the second option worked, I used it in a project 2 years ago, I did not want to use it because it clearly seems a bad practice and it also does not seem the correct way to do it, but apparently it remains the only solution for something so simple. I see several people with the same problem and to this day developers have implemented nothing to get around this problem. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Define your createSwitchNavigator like this

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        StartCheck: StartCheck, // Component

        App: MainStack, // Stack
        Welcome: WelcomeScreen, // Component
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'StartCheck',
        headerMode: 'none',
    }
));
```